# Stop mocked IFormFile from Creating a FileCopy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-core-webapi

While writing Unit Tests for one of my service classes in an ASP.Net Core Web API I needed to mock a `IFormFile`. Therefore I decided to mock it like this (using moq):

```
fileMock.Setup(x => x.CopyToAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
.Callback(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("File Copied");
})
.Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

The Method I want to test happily accepts this mock and all seemed fine until I Checked the File Location I specified for Test Purposes here:
[image: here].

This seemed a little odd to me as I expected that no file would be created (especially because my Callback and Return Statements are never touching the stream). I tried to modify the mock (e.g. without any Callback or with immediately closing the Stream) but no luck the file gets still created.
I then checked my Implementation of the File Saving Operation:

```
public async Task<Result> SaveFileToDiskAsync(string filePath, IFormFile file, CancellationToken token)
{
    //Checking if values are correct
    try
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return Result.Ok();
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     //Logging
    }
}
```

And here is where I am stuck. I am not seeing what is wrong with this method, especially because it seems to do the right thing with copying a file (It is just doing it at the wrong time).
Therefore my Question: Is there a better way to implement either the mock or the Method to stop the FileCreation?

Comment: `var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)` **will** create a file. You are tightly coupling to the actual IO implementation concern. not an abstraction that can be mocked.

Comment: abstract the file stream access. That should give the system the flexibility it needs to be decoupled from implementation concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)
```

**will** create a file.

The system is tightly coupling to the actual IO implementation concern. Not an abstraction that can be mocked.

Abstract the file stream access.

```
public interface IFileStreamProvider {
    Stream Create(string path);
    Stream Open(string path);
    //...
}
```

That should give the system the flexibility it needs to be decoupled from implementation concerns.

```
private readonly IFileStreamProvider disk; //populated via constructor injection.

public async Task<Result> SaveFileToDiskAsync(string filePath, IFormFile file, CancellationToken token) {
    //Checking if values are correct
    try {
        using (var stream = disk.Create(filePath)) {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return Result.Ok();
        }               
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Logging
    }
}
```

And tested in isolation

```
//...

var disk = new MemoryStream(); //
var diskMock = new Mock<IFileStreamProvider>();
diskMock
    .Setup(_ => _.Create(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(disk);

//...
```

While the actual `IFileStreamProvider.Create` implementation will wrap the creation of a `FileStream`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great example and the explanation. That clarified a lot of things.